# FancyBox inline popup hiding background

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a button that shows an inline fancybox popup:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#inlineSearchPopup">
<asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" Text="Search Stories" OnClick="searchButton_Click" />     
</a>

<div id="inlineSearchPopup" style="width: 400px; display: none;">
            <h3>
                Etiam quis mi eu elit</h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis mi eu elit tempor
                facilisis id et neque. Nulla sit amet sem sapien. Vestibulum imperdiet porta ante
                ac ornare. Nulla et lorem eu nibh adipiscing ultricies nec at lacus. Cras laoreet
                ultricies sem, at blandit mi eleifend aliquam. Nunc enim ipsum, vehicula non pretium
                varius, cursus ac tortor. Vivamus fringilla congue laoreet. Quisque ultrices sodales
                orci, quis rhoncus justo auctor in. Phasellus dui eros, bibendum eu feugiat ornare,
                faucibus eu mi. Nunc aliquet tempus sem, id aliquam diam varius ac. Maecenas nisl
                nunc, molestie vitae eleifend vel, iaculis sed magna. Aenean tempus lacus vitae
                orci posuere porttitor eget non felis. Donec lectus elit, aliquam nec eleifend sit
                amet, vestibulum sed nunc.
            </p>
        </div>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<% = Page.ResolveUrl("~/css/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5") %>"
    type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<% = Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5") %>"></script>
<!-- Add Button helper (this is optional) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<% = Page.ResolveUrl("~/css/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5") %>" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<% = Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
             openEffect: 'none',
            closeEffect: 'none'
        });
```

It is popping up and working almost correctly but when the popup does occur it hides the background. I don't want it to hide the background. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you share the link with working code, or fiddle it

Comment: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/ See: inLine link

Comment: i know about the fancy box demo, i meant what you coded

Comment: Above is everything I have coded related to this. It's using ASP.NET server controls and I don't have the site published yet.

Comment: Do you mean its hiding in the background as in a z-index issue? Are you having this problem in all browsers?

Comment: Is your code working as in the fancybox demo? if so, then you are not doing anything wrong. What are you expecting to be different? If you want help, you need to be more specific.

Comment: It works the same except it hides the background of the site unlike the demo.